# Retrieving array of objects pointing to a Class which in turn points to another Class in Parse in the same call

Tags: android, arrays, pointers, object, parse-platform

I have a class called "Order" which has one pointer that points to a class called Product. To pull the order object and the associated product I use include.("productPointer") which is my pointer column name. This is working fine.

Now this Product class has an array of pointers pointing to another class called ProductImage in a column called "imagePointer". Now when I call the Order object, I want to pull the Product object (which I am able to do) and along with that the objects in ProductImage as well within the same query.

Basically the Product can have multiple images which are not a fixed number. To overcome this I have made another class called ProductImage and reference all the images from that via array of pointers to specific ProductObjects.

I am unable to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do multi level includes using dot notation, for your example it'd be:

```
yourQuery.include("productPointer").include("productPointer.imagePointer")
```

If you change the `imagePointer` column from Product to an array you can also use this query to prefetch all columns you need:

```
yourQuery.include("productPointer").include("productPointer.imageArray")
```

Comment: so to get the productPointer i do
List<ParseObject> list= getList("productPointer") and loop over these.
So for the images do I do List<ParseObject> list= getList("productPointer.imagePointer")

Comment: no, the dot notation is only for queries, you have to get the list through the class queried. I think you are querying to `Order` so `List<ParseObject> list= getList("productPointer")` is ok, now when you loop over them you have to call `eachProduct.getList('imagePointer')` if imagePointer is an array, if it´s a pointer `eachProduct.getParseObject('imagePointer')`

Comment: when i type yourQuery.include("productPointer").include("productPointer.imagePointer")Error:(84, 40) error: void cannot be dereference

Comment: How are you creating the Query? You should have something like: `ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Order");
query.include("productPointer").include("productPointer.imagePointer");`

Comment: ParseQuery<ParseStyleBoard> query= ParseStyleBoard.getQuery();
        Log.d("starting ", "Parse query");
        query.include("productPointer");
        query.include("productPointer.productImageId");
and ParseQuery<styleBoard> is a subclass which is working fine.
This is being called successfully, will pull the data in a list now

 im getting an invalid session token when which is weird cause both classed ACL is set to public read and write. But if i login then it works. With only one query.include it was working without the Login..

Comment: Change it to this: `ParseQuery<ParseStyleBoard> query = ParseStyleBoard.getQuery().include("productPointer").query.include("productPointer.productImageId")`. Many methods of parse query returns same query (builder pattern) you you can concat them.

Comment: No even this isnt working. Iv placed two query.include and its working fine. Im also pulling List of arrays from the Product parseObject so its working fine. Thanks anyway. The query.include("productPointer.imagePointer") is working fine for me.